# Access to specific directory in android 11

Tags: android

I want get access to Whatsapp statuses directory. I use from this code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.R){
            val sm =getSystemService(STORAGE_SERVICE) as StorageManager
            val intent=sm.primaryStorageVolume.createOpenDocumentTreeIntent()
            val strDir="Android%2Fmedia%2Fcom.whatsapp%2FWhatsApp%2FMedia%2F.Statuses"
            var uri=intent.getParcelableExtra<Uri>(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI)!!
            var scheme=uri.toString()
            scheme=scheme.replace("/root/", "/document/")
            scheme+="%3A$strDir"
            uri= Uri.parse(scheme)
            intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, uri)
            registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){
                if (it.resultCode== RESULT_OK){
                    contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(
                        it.data?.data!!,
                        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                    )
                    val statusesDir=DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, it.data?.data!!)!!
                    val statuses=statusesDir.listFiles()
                    statuses.forEach {
                        Log.i("___", it.name!!)
                    }
                }
            }.launch(
                Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE).apply {
                    putExtra(
                        DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI,
                        uri
                    )
                }
            )
        }
```

I have two questions:

1- How can I check the folder access next time before sending intent?

2- How can I find directory direct path for next time?

Comment: `want get access to Whatsapp statuses directory. I use from this code:` I have only one question: do you succeede?

Comment: Yes. use from `context.contentResolver.persistedUriPermissions`

Comment: ????? I dont understand your answer. Please tell if initial uri works as that was my question.  Where does it open.

Answer (score 0):

Save the folder and Uri with SharedPreferences on onActivityResult,
next time check if it was saved or request for the permission